# Expanding/Minimizing Accordion not working properly

Tags: html, css

I created an accordion but when I select try to minimize "Button 2" it minimizes "Button 1" instead. However, when I try to minimize "Button 1", it minimizes itself just fine. I posted the code on JS Fiddle for your reference so you can see this in action:

https://jsfiddle.net/tay7p4eL/2/

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix this so that Button 2 minimizes itself properly and doesn't effect Button 1??

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap-collabsible">
    <input checked="checked" class="toggle" id="collapsible" type="checkbox" checked> <label class="lbl-toggle" for="collapsible" tabindex="0">Button 1</label>
    <div class="collapsible-content">
        <div class="content-inner">
            <p>Test 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Button 2

Test 2

CSS:

```
.wrap-collabsible {
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem 0;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}

.lbl-toggle {
  display: block;

  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;

  padding: 1rem;

  color: #A77B0E;
  background: #FAE042;

  cursor: pointer;

  border-radius: 7px;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

.lbl-toggle:hover {
  color: #7C5A0B;
}

.lbl-toggle::before {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;

  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid currentColor;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: .7rem;
  transform: translateY(-2px);

  transition: transform .2s ease-out;
}

.toggle:checked + .lbl-toggle::before {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-3px);
}

.collapsible-content {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .25s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle:checked + .lbl-toggle + .collapsible-content {
  max-height: 350px;
}

.toggle:checked + .lbl-toggle {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.collapsible-content .content-inner {
  background: rgba(250, 224, 66, .2);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(250, 224, 66, .45);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your html, you have assigned the same id "collapsible" to both your "Button 1" and "Button 2" inputs. Assigning unique ids to each input (and correcting the corresponding label html) should resolve your issue.

For example:

```css
.wrap-collabsible {
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem 0;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}

.lbl-toggle {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #A77B0E;
  background: #FAE042;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 7px;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

.lbl-toggle:hover {
  color: #7C5A0B;
}

.lbl-toggle::before {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid currentColor;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: .7rem;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  transition: transform .2s ease-out;
}

.toggle:checked + .lbl-toggle::before {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-3px);
}

.collapsible-content {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .25s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle:checked + .lbl-toggle + .collapsible-content {
  max-height: 350px;
}

.toggle:checked + .lbl-toggle {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.collapsible-content .content-inner {
  background: rgba(250, 224, 66, .2);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(250, 224, 66, .45);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-collabsible">
      <input checked="checked" class="toggle" id="collapsible1" type="checkbox" checked> 
      <label class="lbl-toggle" for="collapsible1" tabindex="0">Button 1</label>
      <div class="collapsible-content">
        <div class="content-inner">
          <p>Test 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      
    <div class="wrap-collabsible">
      <input checked="checked" class="toggle" id="collapsible2" type="checkbox" checked> 
      <label class="lbl-toggle" for="collapsible2" tabindex="0">Button 2</label>
      <div class="collapsible-content">
        <div class="content-inner">
          <p>Test 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Any way of modifying my CSS with different ID's so that it takes effect on all of them without having to copy and pasting the code twice in the CSS for unique IDs? Basically, what I'm saying is - how can I declare the same CSS for each unique ID here? I cannot seem to figure it out! :(

Comment: Your css is fine as it is. The issue was invalid html (id attributes need to be unique). Edited my answer so that you can run the code snippet, see the individual toggles working correctly with only html corrections and no changes to your css.

Comment: This works and makes so much more sense to me now. Thanks!